# Sip/Voip Call Support for all device in android

Tags: android, sip

I build application for `sip/voip` call. It is supportable for only `Samsung`, `HTC` , `Motorola` device. but sip call is not supportable for Micromax, Xolo etc etc device.so i want to build app for supportable sip call for all devices.how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually some Samsung devices also doesn't support SIP/Voip(like s3)
There are some library you can use to refer for building your own SIP/VOIP client.

I used to build Voip client using CSipSimple, it works fine on almost all devices i tested.

1. CSipSimple
2. IMSDroid
3. SIPDroid

http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/

https://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/

https://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/

Comment: how to use this in our project?@NullByte

Comment: Download CSipSimple, check out all code, you will understand how to build your client